# iTunes Books lists

Tags: itunes, books

I have little space on the iPad and I need to do the following:

- On work days: sync a books collection that relates to work
- On off-word days: sync a books collection that is "just for me"

Short of creating 2 iTunes profiles, how would you solve this?

With music, I can just create "playlists" and selectively sync those...

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your device in the left pane. Open the Books tab.
2. Under “Sync Books”, mark Selected Books.
3. Select which books you want to sync, each time you sync.

Though books can be added to playlists, I can’t seem to figure out how to sync them.

Comment: Yes, this is one-by-one clicking unfortunately... isn't it?

Comment: Yep. Though you can create playlists of books, there’s no way to mark them up for sync. That’s really stupid.